# Load data from a file containing json objects without a delimiter

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to load data from files in s3 into snowflake. For reasons out of my control the content of these files are JSON objects without a delimiter, for example, a single file would be as such:
`{"key1":"valueA","key2":"valueB"}{"key1":"valueC","key2":"valueD"}`

So I can't create a file format with any delimiter. I had an idea of using `'}{'` and then wrapping both records (JSON objects) with the missing parentheses, but there is no such option and record delimiter accepts a single char. Another approach might be using a regex to capture a single record but I don't see anything in the docs.

Is there a better way of dealing with this?

Comment: Make no mistake: this is not JSON and you should make sure your provider doesn't get away with claiming it is

Comment: Stick with known standards : http://ndjson.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the file as a whole is not valid JSON, you can't read it as semi-structured data.

You can read the file as CSV and reassemble with a little cleverness if the objects are split at internal `}` characters:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE T (
  LINE_NO NUMBER IDENTITY,
  JSON TEXT
);

COPY INTO T(JSON) FROM (SELECT $1||'}' JSON FROM @my_stage/json.csv)
FILE_FORMAT = (TYPE = CSV FIELD_DELIMITER = NONE RECORD_DELIMITER='}');

SELECT REC_NO, PARSE_JSON(LISTAGG(JSON) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY LINE_NO)) JSON FROM (
  SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN NEW_OBJ AND MOD(QUOTE_QTY_AGG - QUOTE_QTY, 2) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        OVER (ORDER BY LINE_NO) REC_NO, LINE_NO, JSON
  FROM (
    SELECT
      REGEXP_COUNT(JSON, '"') - REGEXP_COUNT(JSON, '\\\\"') QUOTE_QTY,
      SUM(REGEXP_COUNT(JSON, '"') - REGEXP_COUNT(JSON, '\\\\"'))
          OVER (ORDER BY LINE_NO) QUOTE_QTY_AGG,
      REGEXP_LIKE(JSON, '\\s*\\{\\s*".*') NEW_OBJ,
      LINE_NO, JSON
    FROM T
  )
)
GROUP BY REC_NO
ORDER BY REC_NO;
```

The above query will (sticking my head out here) parse *any* "valid" (modulo multiple objects) JSON, even objects like `{"{a}": "{{b}}"}`.  It does so by observing the following:

- A new object starts with `{"`, but not if the `{`is inside a string
- The start of the current line is not inside a string if the number of unescaped doublequote characters in preceding lines is even

Comment: I agree - this is not JSON.

Comment: This is a great hack. However, it seems to fail when a field value in the JSON contains brackets. e.g, {"a": "{"b":"c"}"}

Comment: @LouaiGhalia You were right, although your JSON seems invalid, that the regexp for QUOTE_QTY '(\\\\.|[^"])*"' was incorrect.  I've replaced it with two simple regexps instead in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Hans's approach can work, but it is quite a (nice!) hack.

There's a simpler way *if* your files are not too large (up to a few megabytes).

Then you can read the entire file as a single `varchar` value, and post-process it with something like below. In short, we

- split the string by `}{`
- "fix" the missing curlies if needed
- `parse_json` the result:

Here's the code:

```
create or replace table x(v varchar) as 
  select * from values('{"a":1}{"b":2}{"c":{"cc":3}}');

select parse_json(
  concat(
    iff(startswith(spl.value,'{'), '', '{'),  -- add '{' if needed 
    spl.value,
    iff(endswith(spl.value, '}'), '', '}')  -- add '}' if needed
  )
) rec 
from x, lateral split_to_table(v, '}{') spl;
-------------+
     REC     |
-------------+
 {           |
   "a": 1    |
 }           |
 {           |
   "b": 2    |
 }           |
 {           |
   "c": {    |
     "cc": 3 |
   }         |
 }           |
-------------+
```

Comment: I started out with reading the file as a single line, but you cannot split 100% correctly in all cases with Snowflake regexps (they don't backtrack).  I revised my query above so that it now handles _any_ object, and you have to maintain parse state to do so.  Unfortunately, the complexity level is now ridiculous.